# gnuplot: how do I rotate the title

Tags: gnuplot

I rotate the plot with:

```
set xtic rotate
set y2tic rotate 
plot ... rotate
```

However, the title stays vertical on the right side. How do I rotate it to the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, perhaps by using `set y2label` rather than `set title`.

```
set margins 8,8,4,4
set link x2

unset xtics
set xrange [-3:11]
set yrange [*:*] reverse
set yzeroaxis
set ytics rotate by -90
set x2tics -2,2,10
set x2tics rotate by -90  offset 0,1
unset key

set ylabel "I'm really the y label" offset 1,0 rotate by -90
set y2label "This is y2label turned sideways" offset 1,0 rotate by -90
set y2label font ",20"


plot [u=-10:10] '+' using (10.*sinc($1)):($1) with lines
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, so there are axis tics and labels.